# Angular, adding scope is breaking my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble getting this directive to work properly, It was working fine until I tried adding a scope to link a function. Here's what I have so far

The directive (in requirejs format hence the module/component name stuff) :

```
  angular.module(metadata.moduleName, [
        filterFieldControl.moduleName
    ]).directive(metadata.componentName,
        function(scope) {
            return {
                controller: filterFieldControl.componentName,
                restrict: 'C',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    filterFn: '='
                },
                template: builderResultFiltersHTML
            };
        }
    );
```

The controller

```
 angular.module(metadata.moduleName, []).controller(metadata.componentName, [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {

            $scope.filterChange = function() {
                $scope.filterFn();
            };

        }
    ]);
```

The template:

```
  <div>
<ul>{{filter.name}}
    <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterObject[filter.name][value]" ng-change="filterChange()">{{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where it is being used (and maybe some of the issue is it's being repeated?)

```
   <div ng-repeat="result in searchResults.results" class="builder-search-result" filter-fn="filterClicked" ></div>
```

So if I take out the scope from the directive it works fine. If i add it in, there are no errors in console but nohting shows up.

If I remove this, it works :

```
scope: {
        filterFn: '='
        },
```

Can't seem to figure out why. Could use some ideas.

Edit: added fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vt1uasw7/31/ - you will notice if you remove the scope part of the directive, everything shows up fine.

Comment: Is `filterClicked` a function?

Comment: yeah in the controller outside of it @MichaelBenford

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker or something showing your problem?

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear what the problem is. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Try using '&' instead of '='

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `scope: { ... }` in a directive, you're telling Angular to create an *isolate scope*, which is a scope that doesn't prototypally inherit from any other scope.

Now, take a look at your directive's template:

```
<div>in
  <ul>{{filter.name}}
    <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-change="filterChange()">{{value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Both `filter` and `filterChange()` are defined in the controller's scope, and your directive can't access them because it has its own private scope.

You can fix your code by doing one of two things:

1. Use `$parent.filter` and `$parent.filterChange()`;
2. Add `filter` and `filterChange` to the directive's isolate scope:

   ```
   scope: {
     filter: '=',
     filterChange: '&'
   }
   ```

I suggest #2. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vt1uasw7/37/)'s your updated fiddle.